# Can we use Principal Components(PCA) with other features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have a dataset of 10 features.  Three of these are categorical; when I apply one-hot encoding to these three, they blow up into 96 features. I reduced these 96 features into 20 by PCA.

I plan to use the 20 principal components and the remaining 7 features as my final feature set. Is this a good idea: to combine principal components with actual features?

Comment: [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to post your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCA tends to represent a combination of actual features, most of the times this combination leads to some information loss. That usually is fair trade-off by the dimensionality reduction. Adding those actual features won't get you dimensionality too large and will get "back" some information lost by PCA.

But my advice would still be to try it both. and choose the one that leads better results (given your specification)

Comment: Thanks! But I am adding only those features back that I do not run PCA on.

Comment: The advice stills the same, but now I can't see why this brings a question, I mean, there is no problem in mixing features from different sources (even if the source is a dimensionality reduction algorithm). Information is information, let the machine decide what's important

Comment: Sure Thanks! Will try both ways!

Answer (score 1):

There is no theoretical problem with this approach.  From a statistical standpoint, all you've done is to *exclude* those seven features from the PCA reduction.  This implies that you know, *a priori*, that those seven features are principal components -- that they're significant to the results, without having to analyze them for independence from the other features, and for relevance.

As `loeschet` already mentioned, you should try it both ways: once the way you're proposing, and once with all 103 features included in your PCA phase.  See which gives you better results.  Much of data set analysis consists of trying different approaches to see which gives you the best empirical results.

Comment: The problem was with 103 features and 200K records, the runtime on my SVM was pretty high (almost 1.5 hours) with a 90% accuracy and 92% AUC, thats why the mix and match!

Comment: Read that again: I did not suggest that you put 103 features into your SVM run; I suggested that you feed them all to the PCA *before* the SVM construction.